# using docker buildx failed to push image to resgistry: no such host

Tags: docker

I have added my registry vm hostname to `/etc/hosts` and `docker pull <registry_name>/<imagename>` works.
However when I try to use `docker buildx build .. --push` command to push to the same registry, it throws error:

```
 => ERROR exporting to image                                                                                                             2.3s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                  1.9s
 => => exporting manifest sha256:...                                        0.1s
 => => exporting config sha256:...                                          0.0s
 => => exporting manifest sha256: ...                                       0.0s
 => => exporting config sha256:                                             0.1s
 => => exporting manifest list sha256:                                      0.0s
 => => pushing layers                                                                                                                    0.1s
------
 > exporting to image:
------
failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to do request: Head https://<registry_name>/v2/...: dial tcp: lookup <registry_name> : no such host
```

Does docker buildx does not look /etc/hosts?

Comment: Further updates: the above command works for docker hub push however does not work on even localhost registry setup on that vm
Fails with same error:
```failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to do request: Head https://localhost/v2/csi-node-driver-nam/blobs/sha256:: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:443: connect: connection refused
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be achieved by setting `--driver-opt` to use host network.

Comment: Yup, thanks for the tip @NamrataB. The following command worked for me: `docker buildx create --driver-opt=network=host`